# send and recive data using select() function

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select

I'm writing client code that talking with a server, send and recive data.
I'm using select function to monitor both file descriptors - 0 as the stdin fd and 4(socket_dect) as the socket fd.
the main idea is to find whitch of the fd's is active at the moment, if the STDING is active, that ill read it and send the data to the server, if the socket fd is active then ill recive the data and print it.
i don't know why but nathing happanes when I run this client.
this is my code :

// chat client 
// written by omri

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define PORT 9034 // defined port like the server
#define STDIN 0

void main()
{
    struct timeval tv; // time values for select function
    int activity = 0 ;
    int ready; // contains the result of the select function
    char buf[256];
    int len = strlen(buf);
    int byte_sent,i;
    int socket_dect; // creating socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_in ServerInfo;
    fd_set readfds;

    // creating a new socket, its a number represent a file descriptor
    // socket args : 1)ip protocol ipv4,second tcp/udp, third is number of protocol used
    socket_dect = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(socket_dect == -1){
        perror("error creating socket");
    }
    // fill the values of the server
    ServerInfo.sin_family = AF_INET; // ipv4
    ServerInfo.sin_port = htons(PORT); // port number
    //ServerInfo.sin_addr = 127.0.0.1; 
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &ServerInfo.sin_addr);//insert the ip to the sin addr

    //fill the values of the time for the select function
    tv.tv_sec = 5; // 5 sec
    tv.tv_usec = 0; // 0 mili sec
    FD_ZERO(&readfds); // clear the socket set
    for(i = 0; i<= socket_dect; i++){
        FD_SET(i,&readfds);// set the sockets
    }

    // making the connection to the server
    //ServerInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // another way to put ip addr
    connect(socket_dect,(struct sockaddr *)&ServerInfo,sizeof(ServerInfo)); // connected to the server
    printf("after connect");
    while(1){
        ready = select(socket_dect,&readfds,NULL,NULL,&tv); 
        printf("%d is ready",ready);
        if(ready < 0){
            perror("select error");
            printf("select error");
        }
        // reading from STDIN to buff
        else if(ready == STDIN_FILENO){
            if(fread(buf,256,1,&readfds) < 0){
                printf("read error");
                perror("read error");
            }   
            if(send(socket_dect,buf,len,NULL) < 0){
                perror("send connection");
                printf("send error");
            }//end if send
        }//end elseif STDIN
        else if(ready == socket_dect){
            if(recv(socket_dect,buf,len,0) < 0 ){
                printf("recv error");
            }
            printf("data recived is :%s",buf);   
        }//end elseif
        else{
            printf("none is ready");
        }
    }//end while
}//end main
```

Comment: From the [select man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select): "nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, **plus 1**".

Comment: `if(ready == STDIN_FILENO)` and that is not the right way to check which file descriptor is ready. Again, refer to the man page: "On exit, the sets are modified in place to indicate which file descriptors actually changed status."

Comment: Because `select` modifies the fd sets passed to it, the fd sets, `readfds` in this case, need to be set again for each iteration of the loop. Also, the set should only contain `STDIN_FILENO` and `socket_dect` instead of all the file descriptors between those values as is being done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters two plus more issues.

This

```
ready = select(socket_dect,&readfds,NULL,NULL,&tv);
```

should be

```
ready = select(socket_dect + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

From [`man select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html):

> *nfds* is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.

---

Instead of

```
if(ready == STDIN_FILENO)
```

use

```
if (FD_ISET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds)
```

---

`select()` modifies the parameters passed, so you need to re-initialise them every time before calling `select()`, that is inside the loop.

---

Also you ***must*** test all system calls for their outcome. This includes `connect()`.

---

Also^2 you may not assume `recv()` returns as many bytes as it was told to (`len` here). It may return having received few. To make sure you got as much as you wanted loop around `recv()` counting.